# How to Add Custom Swift View Control in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I looked for a custom label with marquee feature. So i decided to implement this from git: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift

I downloaded it as a zip file and copied the .swift file to my project. But when I open Main.storyboard, I could not find the MarqueeLabel in the list of views.

How should I properly add this custom label?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add QuartzCore.framework as it stated in the documents. Then try to add the MarqueeLabel through code instead of using storyboard to see if it would work that way.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be in the list of views. Create a UILabel as normal, then select it in the identity inspector and change its type to MarqueeLabel.